# Objective-c: How to build funkyoverlaywindow starting with main.m

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm looking at an Objective-C sample project at:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/FunkyOverlayWindow/Introduction/Intro.html

I don't understand how main.m passes control to the other classes/objects.

Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to build that app, step by step. My first step was to get  main.m to compile. I believe this is the starting point for most applications. I don't know what to add/compile next, because main.m does't mention/refer to any of the classes in that project.

Any ideas?

Comment: main.m , it was a typo I updated the Q.

Comment: I'm going bare bones on this one to learn objective c 100%. So I don't use Xcode, I use this terminal command to compile:   clang -framework AppKit main.m

Comment: Add at least one more useful tag to your question, if possible, to make this question more reachable by users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The entry point in Objective-C programs is the function called `main()`. See the following code from main.m

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  return NSApplicationMain(argc, (const char **)argue);

}
```

The `main()` function begins by calling a function named `NSApplicationMain()` that is cocoa framework function and not shown to user, which is functionally similar to the following:

```
void NSApplicationMain(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{

  [NSApplication sharedApplication];

  [NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myMain" owner:NSApp];

  [NSApp run];

}
```

Thus, `[NSBundle loadNibNamed:@"myMain" owner:NSApp]` is called by `NSApplicationMain` function and in this time, `@"myMain"` is identifier for Main Interface(as MainMenu.xib within sample source)
finally MainMenu.xib is run, and then `OverlayWindow` that is main window of MainMenu.xib will be run.

Comment: This is basically correct and comes right out of the [`NSApplication` class overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/). Implicit in this is the expectation that a Cocoa app is a bundled app, not a standalone executable, and has an Info.plist and a main NIB or storyboard. Rather than `NSApplication`, it actually uses the class named by the `NSPrincipalClass` Info.plist key. Instead of "myMain", it uses the `NSMainNibFile` key. The main NIB usually instantiates and connects an app delegate and main menu.

Answer (score 0):

I appreciate, and understand perfectly, how you could not want to use Xcode - especially if, like me, you come from a Unix/GCC/Makefile environment. However, there are some things that are really quite hard to do without the Xcode GUI and linking buttons and widgets to your code is one of those things.

In Xcode, you click the button in your user interface and drag a line to the code attached to it - these are called `IBOutlet`s and `IBAction`s. So, my first suggestion is to Google those two terms.

Secondly, I recommend you watch this video on YouTube to understand what the XIB/NIB is and how to link it to your code and then you can try and do it without Xcode once you get the concept... [video showing linking buttons to code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgrDSW0dHy4).